# Setting ARCamera exposure time in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm working hard on an application using ARKit. In order for the app to fulfil its main purpose, which is to track a face, good lighting condition is essential. In AVFoundation, there is a function to set the custom exposure time. But I didn't find a way to set it in ARKit. I just found the get object `frame.camera.exposureDuration`. So how do I set exposure time with ARKit? Where do I have to call the function?

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    // frame.camera.exposureDuration = ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Alas, but you can't change camera's exposure parameters in ARKit 3.5 and ARKit 3.0. There are two instance properties [exposureDuration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/3182986-exposureduration) and [exposureOffset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/3194569-exposureoffset) but they are only gettable, not settable.

```
var exposureDuration: TimeInterval { get }

var exposureOffset: Float { get }
```

> However, if you use ARKit 3.5 and devices with LiDAR scanner you don't depend on lighting conditions in your environment anymore. That's because Apple LiDAR scanner allows you track surfaces even **in a complete darkness**.

Nevertheless, you can implement `AVFoundation` and `Metal` methodology to change ARKit's camera's exposure parameters but it's a real challenge for you as a developer.

Comment: Thanks for you're answer. You saved me a lot of time. Once I read that the framerate has an effect on the exposure time in AVFoundation? Can I take advantage of this in ARKit?

Comment: In ARKit all camera settings are locked now, you can't even reduce frame rate officially (it's 60 fps). You can only "make an unofficial drop frame" to reduce a frame rate but I'm sure it does not affect camera's exposure.

Comment: Can you explain more accurate how to use Metal and AVFoundation methodology to change ARKit's cavers exposuretime?

Comment: It might look like this: http://metalkit.org/2017/07/29/using-arkit-with-metal.html